# Does anyone know if concrete blocks with half-moon tops are made?

Tags: fence, masonry, concrete-block, retaining-wall

I'm planning to finish a concrete block fence and would like to cap it with a rounded half-moon style block for aesthetics (the whole thing will be covered with surface-bonding cement for an adobe-ish look). Trouble is, I'm having difficulty finding any and am not altogether convinced that such blocks exist. So do they?

[image: block wall topped with half-moon block]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They make them. Not concrete blocks per se but other precast concrete units. You'll need to find out if you're local suppliers carry them or you have a precast stone manufacturer near you.

The family of products you're talking about, which includes not only the half round but other shapes, are called [concrete coping stones](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=concrete%20coping%20stones). That should help you ask around to see if you can get them.